# regex get several parts of the string and then replace everything with new string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$string1="asdfgsdfgsdf[quote=user9 postID=345]sdfgsdfgsdfgdsfg";
```

I want to get all chars between `"quote="` and `" "` into $chars1, then between `"postID="` and `" "` into $chars2 and then finally I want to change all symbols from (including) `"[quote"` to `"]"` on other string `$string2='_test_'` ;

So in the end I should get 
`$chars1="user9";` ,
`$chars2="345";` ,
 and transformed $string1

```
$string1="asdfgsdfgsdf_test_sdfgsdfgsdfgdsfg";
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Before asking *How can I do that?* you should ask *What did I do?* and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `preg_replace_callback` with a regex with 2 captured groups:

```
$string1 = "asdfgsdfgsdf[quote=user9 postID=345]sdfgsdfgsdfgdsfg";

$string1 = preg_replace_callback (
   '/\[quote=(\S*)\s+postID=([^]\s]*)[^]]*]/',
   function($m) use(&$chars1, &$chars2) {
      $chars1 = $m[1];
      $chars2 = $m[2];
      return "_test_";
   },
   $string1
);

var_dump($string1, $chars1, $chars2);
```

**Output:**

```
string(34) "asdfgsdfgsdf_test_sdfgsdfgsdfgdsfg"
string(5) "user9"
string(3) "345"
```